# I want to calculate the sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sum

I want to calculate the sum with c++,

Sum = 1 + ... + (2n - 1) = n2

I tried like

```
double s = 0;
int i = 1;
int n = 5;
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    double val = (double)i / (i + 1);
    if (i % 2 != 0){
        val *= -1.;
    }
    s += val;
}
```

but is not right correct. can someone help me?

Comment: I don't see any division in your desired series.

Comment: TDD: try with `n == 1`, then `n == 3`...

Comment: The for loop doesn't look anything like the mathematical equation...

Comment: @Gabriel  It is entirely different compared with what you showed in your post before its editing.

Comment: There are no negative terms in your series, so why are you multiplying by -1?

Comment: Please change your question consistently without changing the overall contents of the question. The first version was `1-1*3+1*3*5-...`, i.e., an alternating sum of double factorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your current, **completely changed**, task asks of you is to is add the odd numbers from `1` to `2n-1` to obtain the number `n^2=n*n`

```
for(i=1; i<2*n; i+=2) sum +=i
```

or

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) sum += 2*i-1
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

---

Note that for the original task before the heavy edits, the alternating sum of double factorials, the Horner-Ruffini scheme  gives the formula

```
1-1*3+1*3*5-...+-1*3*...*(2n-1) = 1-3*(1-5*(1-7*(1-....*(1-(2n-1))...)))
```

which gives the loop

```
sum = 1;

for(i=n-1; i>0; i--) 
    sum = 1-(2*i+1)*sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
long sum = 0;
long val = 1;
int n = 5;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    val *= (2*i - 1);
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        val *= -1;
    }
    sum += val;
}

return sum;
```

Use long because double are for decimal values (not this case)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter a positive integer number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        long long int sum  = 0;
        long long int item = 1;

        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            item *= 2 * i - 1;
            sum  += ( i % 2 == 0 ? - item : item );
        }

        std::cout << "\nSum is equal to " << sum << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a positive integer number (0-exit): 10

Sum is equal to -622171082

Enter a positive integer number (0-exit): 0
```

Comment: @LutzL It is an answer to the original post before it was edited.:) I do no know why the original post was rewritten after my answer.

Comment: I then saw that by checking the edit log and reverted my actions.